# problem with javascript updating mathJax equation

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I have a bit of code where I am updating some of the variables in a mathJax equation in javascript.  It works fine on the first pass (i.e. refreshing the page), but when I update the variables on a second pass, the equation is shown as Latex code instead of the rendered equation.

```
document.getElementById("sumstdeveq").innerHTML="$$ \\sqrt{("+stdev1+")^2+("+stdev2+")^2} $$";
```

This line works fine on the first pass, but when I update stdev1 and stdev2 and run this line again, it just shows the code.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yangchris16/k8us0hLt/6/

change the value in one of the input text boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too clued up on MathJax but adding the following line worked on the fiddle.

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,this.formula]);
```

Right after the line you mentioned:

```
stdev1=0.2;
stdev2=0.05;

updatecalcs();

function updatecalcs(){
    stdev1=parseFloat(document.getElementById("stdev1in").value);
    stdev2=parseFloat(document.getElementById("stdev2in").value);

    document.getElementById("sumstdeveq").innerHTML="$$ \\sqrt{("+stdev1+")^2+("+stdev2+")^2} $$";
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,this.formula]);
}
```

Comment: awesome!  that works for me.  I guess I need to read the documentation a little more clearly to understand the process.